# Why I only can ssh a server via VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn

I used to connect to a linux server via SSH (using MobaXterm). Today, I couldn't connect to the server via ssh. my internet was okay and I could browse other sites. I also pinged the server and it didn't respond.

Then, I connected to a VPN and tried to connect to the server, now I could connect to the server via ssh, however `ping` to the server still didn't work!

I just wonder why the VPN makes it enable to connect to the server, but I can't without it (at least for today). How can I fix it ( to connect without need for the VPN).

Comment: When you use a VPN, your traffic appears to originate from the VPN server, not your own IP address.  This server that you're connecting to may have blocked a range of addresses that included your IP address, but not the VPN server's IP address.

Comment: @MikeAndrews Now it again was fixed! So, I doubt that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

Like what @Mike Andrews says, that is one case. there is still the other case.

It Seems like your own server's IP has been blocked by something like Firewall around your Internet.

The VPN act as a tunnel when you attempt to connect to you server via ssh through the VPN. The information in the tunnel that may has been encrypted by the VPN. While the Firewall has not recognized the VPN's IP address and blocked it.